# Swift, Joining (Implicitly Unwrapped) Optional Strings with a joiner

Tags: ios, swift, join, forced-unwrapping

I've tried to join some `[String!]`. So i'm making like [this](https://gist.github.com/wanbok/ce854325a471dd15cc1e):

```
extension String {
    func join(strings: String!... ) -> String {
        return self.join(strings.filter({ $0?.isEmpty == false }).map {$0 as String})
    }
}

var country: String! = nil
var city: String! = ""
var address: String! = "Nowon"
var detailAddress: String! = "Gongneung-dong"

let combinedAddress = " ".join(country, city, address, detailAddress)
```

But, still it seems to be complicated. How do i optimize this?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What output or errors are you getting? If the code is working as expected, and your question is just about optimization, why do you feel like you have to optimize? Is the code a severe bottleneck? Remember the general rule of thumb - code legibly first, and optimize only when necessary.

Comment: @AaronD I think it's complicated at unwrapping processes. And i guessed that the way exists simpler then this. Anyway, now i remember - code legibly first, and optimize only when necessary. Thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you always know that they can be unwrapped, then you can easily join strings

```
var a = "this is a "
var b = "this is b "
var c = "this is c"
let myString = a + b + c
```

I do similar things in my code but first I check if a string is empty

```
if a.isEmpty == false { }
```

Is a quick way to do that

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If they can be unwrapped, we can just use `join` function in `String`.